# Asymmetric Op-Amp Output - Transconductance Amplifier

Tags: operational-amplifier, transconductance-amplifier

I'll preface this post by saying I am a power engineer working in the utility world and my electronics knowledge is very rusty. The last time I worked with electronics was back in undergrad (~6 years ago).

I'm working on a project to generate 60hz sine wave currents. The approach I have right now is to feed a sine-wave into a transconductance amplifier to get my desired currents, which is 0-5 amps and 0-10 amps in a future version. The compliance voltage needed is not very high (maybe 1V at most). Here is my circuit:

[image: circuit]

Everything seems to mostly work, but one issue I can't seem to resolve is an asymmetric output. Here are some oscilloscope traces with a 1ohm resistive load.

Channel 1 = yellow = voltage across the 1ohm resistor

Channel 2 = blue = sine wave input.

[image: oscope1]

The circuit is currently on a PCB that I made, and the input sine wave is from a Rigol signal generator. The input sine wave, measured by the oscilloscope, is ~30mV asymmetric, but I'll chalk that up to measurement/resolution error. The gain of my circuit should be around 4, so I am not sure why I've got such a large difference between the peak values of my current (3.24V vs -2.84V).

[image: oscope2]

Any suggestions on where to start troubleshooting?

Comment: *get my desired currents* Please edit the question to indicate what range of currents you're interested in.

Comment: Just to be clear (ignoring schematic for now), you want something to act as a current source output into a load that won't need more than a volt, plus of minus, of compliance range. And the controlling input is to be a signal generator? I gather your currents are to be around an amp, peak?

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica Updated, my desired current range for this version is 0-5 amps.

Comment: @periblepsis Yes to the first part of your question. The signal generator will eventually be replaced with a microcontroller that generates a sine wave., and my desired current range is 0-5 amps.

Comment: @Bob But you need this to handle two quadrants, right? The current source output must both sink and source current, yes? And given your 5 amps and 1 volt of compliance, this also means the resistance (this ***is*** a resistance and not an inductance or capacitance, right?) cannot be more than 200 milliOhms, right?

Comment: @periblepsis Yes, I need to sink and source current. For some additional context, the current would be injected into a device that we call a "relay" to simulate AC currents in the power system. The relay has current inputs which are very low burden, so the majority of the load resistance would be the leads connecting the amplifier to the relay, which I do not expect to exceed 200 milliOhms.

Comment: @Bob So this means bipolar power sources. If you want lower dissipation, this also means (to me) that the bipolar power sources need to be not too far away from your worst case compliances. So this means BJT to me (or else bootstrapping or extra supply rails for FETs.) However, the 5 A says FET to me, in this case. So, without thinking more about it, all I can say is I'd need to think more about it. I have a topology in mind. But the low voltage and high current is the opposite of what it is really good at (which is high compliance voltage and low current.)

Comment: @Bob Just how inefficient can you accept? Is 70 watts input to get only 5 watts delivered acceptable?

Comment: By my calculations, with a ±1V input (2V pk-pk), you should obtain ±4A load current, and if that load is 1Ω, you would have ±4V across it (8V pk-pk). You only have ±3V (6V pk-pk). The biggest issue here is this gain discrepancy, not the offset, but the two are probably related. The offset is easy to get (accidentally or deliberately) from RV1, and this is my chief suspect for the "asymmetry". I don't see asymmetry, only a gain problem.

Comment: @periblepsis I plan on making 6 of these, so 420W of waste would be challenging from a cooling and power supply perspective.

Comment: @SimonFitch I'm also not sure why I'm not getting a gain of 4. Is it possible for the circuit to have asymmetrical gain? As for RV1, I can adjust it to even out the min/max, but it would result in non-zero current for zero input, and the adjustment does not work for all currents

Comment: @Bob I can't see why there would be any asymmetry. The op-amps' own imperfections wouldn't account for it, unless one of them is bad. Try swapping them. Huge currents flowing in the ground paths can develop a potential difference between two points on the ground node which should be identical. Make sure that load current isn't flowing in any section of ground between the op-amps' various connections to it. And try moving your scope's ground to a different spot on that node, to see if that changes anything.

Comment: @SimonFitch I figured it out, and it was a dumb mistake on my PCB layout. I didn't connect the diff-amp inputs to the current sense resistor correctly on one side of it. I fixed the issue by adding an external jumper, and the output waveform is far more symmetrical now.

https://imgur.com/a/FFuCVw6

https://imgur.com/a/qs7XkTq

Comment: @Bob I agree then. That idea is out. Everything is at question when dealing with low compliance voltages: measurement technique and wiring methods not the least among them. I don't have the time right now for careful thought. So best wishes for now. My idea would cover the situation, I believe, but at the expense of much wasted power. I like the problem though! So I'll +1 the question. _______ Oh!! I just now see you may have an answer for yourself. Great! And you've provided your own answer!!! Cool!

Comment: @periblepsis Yes! It was a dumb mistake on my part, and it stinks that I have to add this jumper on multiple PCBs but I am glad it is an easy fix. I do appreciate you having taken the time to post some responses to my question though.

Answer (score 2):

You're unnecessarily using a differential amplifier. Let me guess - built with 1% resistors, right? Its CMRR will be poor, although the low gain is a saving grace. You got a very slow op-amp, and it needs to deal with up to 1V of common mode at 50Hz-60Hz. This is unnecessary, and that poor OP07 will not do well.

You should be using faster op-amps. They don't need to have much DC precision - since you need none. TL072 will work well in this rather non-critical application.

Instead, ground-reference the current shunt. Then you can use a single-ended amplifier.

You can use a DC servo instead of the potentiometer to get rid of any leftover DC offset, and for that you would use a low offset drift op-amp, like OPA206 or OPA277, or anything comparable.

PCB-layout-wise, the ground plane of the control circuit must be connected to the bottom end of the shunt only, and the supplies for the op-amps must be referenced to that ground plane.

The PCB will affect the performance as much as anything else.

If you asked me to do something like it and be sure it'll work on the first try, I'd use a source follower with a constant-current load - essentially a class-A amplifier. I'd also model the feedback loop stability in SPICE to ensure there's good enough gain and phase margin across the bandwidth.

Instead of a constant-current load, the load can keep the source (high-side) current above say 100mA. The more current the sink sinks, the more current the source will have to source, so if the source is above 100mA, the sink can be open, but as source current crosses under 100mA, the sink kicks in and maintains the source current of 100mA. That way the source will have some minimum conductance and this will stabilize the worst-case loop response.

If you at all can, use a single mosfet for the source and sink. It's much easier that way.

Comment: Thanks for responding. Yes, the PCB is mostly populated with 1% components. Question - where is the "1V of common mode" coming from? The input signal should be a pure sine wave with no DC offset. Since I am only dealing with 60hz signals, I thought the op-amp speed would not be that critical. For my PCB grounding, I have the return current on its own dedicated trace on the PCB which goes to the +/- 5V ground and there is a single connection to the +/- 12V ground.

Comment: Common mode is the voltage on the (+) input of the op amp. For OP07 it should be DC. And OP07 is really not a part anyone should design into new applications.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was poor PCB layout. I didn't connect the current sensor resistor to my diff amp correctly.

Layout:

[image: layout]

I cut the trace and added an external jumper which solved my issue:

[image: jumper]